# mysql command not found in expect script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, expect

I've written a expect script that reads a script file and remotely executes the script.

1481701708951_migration.sh ( The bash script)

This script selects the list of databases where the DDL statement should be executed.

```
db="testdb"
username="root"
password=""
mysql="mysql -u root $db"
$mysql -e "select * from dblist" | grep -v SCHEMANAME > tmp.txt
echo "Migration started..." 
while read line
do
mysql="mysql -u root $line"
$mysql -e "create table test(id int)"

done < tmp.txt
echo "Migration over..."
```

The expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set fh [open 1481701708951_migration.sh r]
set contents [read $fh]
close $fh
spawn ssh sampleusername@192.168.1.1 "bash -c '$contents'"
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "samplepassword\r"
}
}
```

It used to work fine. But now, it's throwing an error `bash: line 4: mysql: command not found`. Can someone help me in solving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you do something to your system in particular that might have caused this issue (upgrade, migration, system restore, ...) ?  What is the output of `which mysql` on your system ? Is your `$PATH` variable correct ?

Comment: @Aserre I tried running `mysql -u root`; it worked. output of `which` is usr/bin/mysql

Comment: Try replacing `mysql="mysql` with `mysql="/usr/bin/mysql` and run again.